# Why does Jackson not require all classes to include @NoArgsConstructor when deserializing?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, lombok

I'm parsing json and have a class that has a parameter of another class type:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Vehicle {
    ...
    @JsonProperty("vehicle_info")
    private VehicleInfo vehicleInfo;

}
```

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class VehicleInfo {
    ...
    @JsonProperty("ev_range")
    private double evRange;
    @JsonProperty("image_urls")
    private List<String> imageUrls;
```

From what I have read and understood, for Jackson to deserialize json, it requires a default no-args constructor on each class. Yet somehow, it deserializes just fine with only the `Vehicle` class defining a no-args ctor.

What's going on here? Why aren't both classes required to define the no-args ctor?

Answer (score 0):

Jackson won't use a constructor with arguments by default, you should inform it to do that using `@JsonCreator` annotation.

**NB : Java give you a No Args Constructor if you did not declare any constructor in your class .**

By default Jackson tries to use the no-args constructor , in the `VehicleInfo` you declare a constructor with arguments using `@AllArgsConstructor` and like that you dont have a NoArgsConstructor in your `VehicleInfo` class.

In the `Vehicle` class , you have two constructors , one with all args and the other with no args and Jackson will use the one without arguments.